# Build fail when build Cordova application in visual studio 2013

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am using `Visual Studio 2013 update 4` with `Cordova tool` installed in it and I am trying to create my first application I do the following steps

1. Create an empty blank application from 
   `File > New > Project > Javascript > Apache cordova apps > Blank App`
2. try to build the application then I got the following error

[image]

Comment: I believe you have to re-install tools for cordova. Might be because Android SDK has not installed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before re-installing the tools, you could try updating the Android SDK using the Android SDK Manager. See this topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551(v=vs.120).aspx#ThirdParty, and read the section under the bullet "Android SDK with the following SDK packages". When the SDK Manager is open, you can choose "Install packages" (see bottom of screenshot) to update packages.

Comment: Once you install the required Android SDK package, you might want to also change the build output to "diagnostic" using Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run --> MSBuild project build output verbosity to print a diagnostic report.